# How to convert string to date without time in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, string, date, time, format

I have try to convert the date like 2017-02-11 string to date but the result give me back something like this 2017-02-10 16:00:00 +0000 . I am using the following code below.

```
let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date) //2017-02-11

    let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let selectedDate = dateFormatter2.date(from: localDate)
    print("Did Select \(selectedDate)") // 2017-02-10 16:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: You can display a date without displaying the time but there is no Date without time

Comment: The date is correct. `print` displays the date in UTC and your local time zone is obviously UTC+8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let dateWithTime = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

let date = dateFormatter.string(from: dateWithTime) // 2/10/17
```

This will format it correctly, but this will be for **display purposes only**. All `Date`s have time.

Answer (score 8):

It's true that there is no `Date` without a time element, but if you need something that you can use to compare whole days, you can get the first moment of a given `Date` using

```
Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: dateWithTime)
```