# Filter array using to and from date

Tags: swift, database, date-comparison

I am using FMDB database to save my records , in my database i have these things name, number, date, title etc.

I want to get records by date , like all records from 2nd feb to 4th Feb, this is my code I am trying to do this but when I compare date i get time also so compare fails

Is it possible to convert string to date without time?

> output:-  :2019-12-01 19:00:00 +0000

I would like to convert into format 2019-12-01 (yyyy-dd-mm)

```
let start = lblTo.text ?? ""
let end = lblFrom.text ?? ""
let dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start)
let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: end)
```

I am trying to filter record from database

```
 for data in readingDataSouce{
            let readingDate = stringToDate(date:data.date ?? "")


            if readingDate > startDate! && readingDate < endDate!
                {

                }


        }


    func stringToDate(date:String) -> Date{
        let start = date
        let dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start)
        return startDate ?? Date()
    }
```

Comment: try using  timeStyle = .none

Comment: yes i did , then it returns same 2019-02-13 19:00:00 +0000

Comment: can you show the output?

Comment: replace the last line of my code below to let correctDate = dateFormatter.string(from: end)

Comment: it returns in this format 15/02/2019 , and its string how i can filter array using string?

Comment: Are you filtering in a database query or an array of objects returned from a  query?

Comment: i have database with lot of records

Comment: I get that but you said in an earlier comment that you want to filter an array so I am not sure what you're asking about. Maybe you can add some code where the date filtering is done.

Comment: @JohnLi You need output in string or date ??

Comment: doe't matter what should be output, i just want to filter by date so if i get output in date without time i can filter

Comment: @JohnLi Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464197/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-time-in-swift-3

Comment: i already check this my problem not solve

Comment: Hey @JohnLi! are you trying to obtain a string or a date object with that format?

Comment: i am trying to obtain date in this formate  2019-12-01 (yyyy-dd-mm) but i get time too :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using timeStyle = .short , change it to .none

```
let end = lblFrom.text ?? ""
let dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
let correctDate = dateFormatter.string(from: end)
```